# Why does adding a public field to an anonymous class in Java not work?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have an example class defined like below:

```
public class FooBar {

  void method1(Foo foo){ // Should be overwritten
    ...
  }

}
```

Later, when I try this:

```
FooBar fooBar = new FooBar(){
  public String name = null;
  @Override
  void method1(Foo foo){
    ...
  }
};

fooBar.name = "Test";
```

I get an error saying that the name field does not exist. Why?

Comment: Please don't use lowercase class names. It took me way too long to decipher "foobar fooBar". Code style conventions exist for a reason.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the *type* of the variable `"fooBar"` is `FooBar` (the *run-time type* of the *object* in said variable is that of the anonymous class implementing `FooBar` which is also a *subtype* of `FooBar`)...

...and the type `FooBar` does not have said member. Hence, a compile error. (Remember, the variable `"fooBar"` can contain any object conforming to `FooBar`, even those without `name`, and thus the compiler rejects the code which is not type-safe.)

**Edit: For one solution, see irreputable's answer which uses a [Local Class Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#247766) to create a new *named type* (to replace the *anonymous type* in the post).**

Java *does not* support a way to do this (mainly: Java does not support useful type inference), although the following does work, even if not very useful:

```
(new foobar(){
  public String name = null;
  @Override
  void method1(Foo foo){
    ...
  }
}).name = "fred";
```

Happy coding.

---

Both Scala and C# support the required type inference, and thus anonymous type specializations, of local variables. (Although C# does not support extending existing types anonymously). Java, however, does not.

Comment: what are the "un-useful" type inferences that Java supports?

Comment: @irreputable See example. The *expression* (`new foobar ...`) has the "correct specialized type [inferred]", but as soon as the expression is assigned to a variable (because of lack of *useful* local type inference) then only nominative types (none of which can describe the anonymous object precisely) can describe the type of object. Hence, *not useful* :(

Comment: @irreputable A few months ago I would have argued that Java had *no* type inference, but there was a good article on the subject by Tony Morris (I think) that I read which demonstrated the limited case above. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find it again... :(

Answer (score 9):

A *local* class would do

```
{
    class MyFooBar extends FooBar{
        String name = null;
        ...
    };

    MyFooBar fooBar = new MyFooBar();

    fooBar.name = "Test";
}
```

Comment: +1 Very clever. I didn't know that a named type (class) could be declared in a block. For those interested, it is a [Local Class Declaration as discussed in 14.3 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#247766).

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an object of type `foobar`.  The compiler only knows about the members defined for the class/interface `foobar`.

Remember, java is a static language, not dynamic.  It doesn't check the object at runtime for what exists, it checks at compile time based on the type declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> void runWithObject(T object, Consumer<T>... progs) {
    for (Consumer<T> prog : progs)
        prog.accept(object);
}
```

and

```
runWithObject(
    new FooBar() {
        String name = null;
        @Override
        void method1(Foo foo) {
            System.out.println("name=" + name);
        }
    },
    object -> object.name = "Test",
    object -> object.method1(new Foo())
);
```

result:

```
name=Test
```

Or you can use `var` like this in Java 10 or later.

```
var fooBar = new FooBar() {
    public String name = null;

    @Override
    void method1(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println("name=" + name);
    }
};
fooBar.name = "Test";
fooBar.method1(new Foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

`fooBar` is a reference to an object of type `foobar`, and such objects do not have a field `name`. Simple as that. And since it’s an anonymous type, the only way to reference that field is through its `this` reference.

Answer (score 0):

`fooBar` type is `foobar` which has not such variable and therefore the code can not be compiled. You can access it by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, this is due to static typing and `FooBar` class does not contain `name`. So it won't work.

I wanted to point out the suggested usage of Anonymous class.

Anonymous class (or close to Closures, maybe lambdas. Similar but *not* same) come from functional programming paradigm, where the states should be immutable.

That being said, why should you user such classes? When you need a quick and short thing to be done which should not necessarily go in a complete class. Example:

```
MyTask() //This is a method
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() { //Anonymous class
        public void run()
        {}
    }).start();
}
```

The understanding of enclosing your implementation only to a function/class is important.

The `scope of the variables defined in the Anonymous class (or closed-over function) should only be used inside the Anonymous class`, it cannot be accessed from other program code.

Therefore, you should not  (and anyway cannot) set `fooBar.name = "Test";`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
Boolean var= new anonymousClass(){
    private String myVar; //String for example
    @Overriden public Boolean method(int i){
          //use myVar and i
    }
    public String setVar(String var){myVar=var; return this;} //Returns self instane
}.setVar("Hello").method(3);
```